# Is there any event when clicked on SolutionExplorer node expander? How to get an empty solution node with an expander?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I was implementing the the feature show all files in the Solution Explorer in Visual studio shell. Somehow Visual Studio already has implementation of Lazy loading of the NonMemmberItems. I also want to implement the same. But If I create an empty folder node, there isn't an expander (triangualar icon or + sign) which expands the node, when clicked. So empty Foldernode doesn't have expander?

1. Can anybody tell me how to implement this?
2. How to get an expandable folder node on which expanded , I can fire and event which will load the files inside the node.
3. How to get such event which can get fired when expanded? (I know there is an event like double click on the node etc.)

Please Anybody, if have any solution reply.

PS: I am implementing a project system.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you writing a VS extension, or are you using a tree-view in a regular application and trying to mimic solution explorer?

Comment: I am writing an Project system, which uses VS shell, which already uses Solution Explorer. @Sahuagin Can you help me is there any event that will get fired when expander is clicked on? And How to create a foldernode (empty) which have expander on which clicked on I can fire the loading of the nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your update provided, you are using a .NET Treeview control and trying to achieve the ondemand loading of the treeview nodes. Many 3rd party vendors such as Telerik, Syncfusion , Devexpress and etc have this functionality for WF & WPF. Hope you are developing the system in WPF platform and you can use them to achieve this. In MS Treeview control, you might need to workaround for achieving this behavior.

http://demos.telerik.com/silverlight/#TreeView/LoadOnDemand

http://help.syncfusion.com/UG/User%20Interface/WPF/Tools/Documents/346318loadondemand.htm